# Jquery plugin Flexslider isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I'm trying to use the Jquery plugin Flexslider on a website that I'm developing. I have my stylesheets and scripts in order like so:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">   
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>'
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

I checked to make sure that Jquery is working by writing just a simple script by putting a red box around all of my divs, and that worked.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...I'm using the code (the HTML as well, but for some reason the ctrl+K isn't working for the code) exactly how the website [tells me to use it](https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Method you use is deprecated, and removed, you probably use newer jQuery version: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ Check alternatives....

Comment: @sinisake If you mean my version of Jquery, it is the most updated version, I just delete the version numbers so when it updates I always have the most updated version (because I overwrite the previous one and don't keep the out of date version.)

Comment: Yes, i guessed so - but, as mentioned, $(window).load will not work for newer versions....

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean, I didn't know that! Let me work on that

Comment: your script initializing flexslider shouldn't be in the `<head>`, it should only be declared after the html for the slider content, or else `$('.flexslider')` will yield nothing, and hence not work.

Comment: @dommmm so I just tried that and it still yielded the same result...nothing. I haven't worked with Jquery very much and the reason I put it in the <head> was because the webpage where I got the plugin from (https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/) told me to do that.

Comment: hmm, that's odd. can you replicate your issue in a jsfiddle/codepen so we can look at what's wrong?